# Prevent add “left” style to sticky menu element

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation-6

I have a theme with left sidebar and content.

Left sidebar code:

```
<div class="medium-2 columns" id="sidebar-left" data-sticky-container>
<div class="sticky" data-sticky data-anchor="content">
   <ul class="accordion" data-accordion data-allow-all-closed="true">
     <li class="accordion-item">
      <a class="accordion-title" href="#">Categories</a>
      <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
        <!-- list of elements -->
      </div>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The Foundation changes the sticky div to:

```
 <div class="sticky is-at-top is-stuck" data-sticky="42hom0-sticky" data-anchor="content" data-resize="rsh5cz-sticky" style="max-width: 257px; margin-top: 1em; top: 0px; bottom: auto; left: 15px;" data-events="resize">
```

How i can prevent Foundation 6 to add "left" style to my sticky menu in the left side-bar?

Comment: So you want the left side of the div to be at 0px instead of 15px?

Answer (score 0):

You can style your data-sticky-container to have padding-left of zero px.

`<div class="medium-2 columns" id="sidebar-left" data-sticky-container style="padding-left:0;">`

or use CSS to complete the same styling using something like:

`.padd-left-0 { padding-left:0; }`

`<div class="medium-2 columns padd-left-0" id="sidebar-left" data-sticky-container>`